# How do I find out all previous versions of python with which my code is compatible

Tags: python, compatibility

I have created a medium sized project in python 2.7.3 containing around 100 modules. I wish to find out with which previous versions of python (ex: 2.6.x, 2.7.x) is my code compatible (before releasing my project in public domain). What is the easiest way to find it out?

Solutions I know -

1. Install multiple versions of python and check in every versions. But I don't have test cases defined yet, so need to define those first.
2. Read and compare changelog of the various python versions I wish to check compatibility for, and accordingly find out.

Kindly provide better solutions.

Comment: I think you would have to compare each module from individual release version.

Comment: @user2246674 it is not easy task since there is lot of code. I believe the python community has a better way of doing so.

Comment: Option 3, post the code and claim that it works with all python versions ever.  Wait for bug reports.  Fix bug reports on versions of python that you care about, revise your previous claim to exclude bug reports that you don't care about.

Comment: @mgilson sir, I think I would actually consider this. :D

Comment: @Guanidene -- FWIW, that's what I do :-P ... Seriously.  (although I do specifically target python2.6 and up and generally do all my testing with python2.7)

Comment: @mgilson sir, I was expecting for some tool (like 2to3) which would point out regions in my code (like builtin function, class constructors) whose implementation is different among the various versions of python i wish to make compatible with; and then I could modify those code regions if required. But I think such a tool is either too complicated or too insignificant to exist. 
Never mind! I think your way would be just fine for me. Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know of a way to get around doing this without some test cases.  Even if your code could run in an older version of python there is no guarantee that it works correctly without a suite of test cases that sufficiently test your code

Comment: "sufficiently testing your code" means having a high degree of [test coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), right?

Comment: Yes but to be clear you can high "test coverage" numbers without actually testing something. Ex. you can have unit tests that run your code and don't assert any results, essentially only testing the code doesn't throw an exception(this is a trivial example but hopefully gets the point across). You need to think about all the cases your code should cover and make sure those are handled, not just high statement coverage

Answer (score 1):

No, what you named is pretty much how it's done, though the What's New pages and the documentation proper may be more useful than the full changelog. Compatibility to such a huge, moving target is infeasible to automate even partially. It's just not as much work as it sounds like, because:

1. Some people do have test suites ;-)
2. You don't (usually) need to consider bugfix releases (such as 2.7.x for various x). It's possible that your code requires a bug fix, but generally the .0 releases are quite reliable and code compatible with x.y.0 can run on any x.y.z version.
3. Thanks to the backwards compatibility policy, it is enough to establish a minimum supported version, all later releases (of the same major version) will stay compatible. This doesn't help in your case as 2.7 is the last 2.x release ever, but if you target, say, 2.5 then you usually don't have to check for 2.6 or 2.7 compatibility.
4. If you keep your eyes open while coding, and have a bit of experience as well as a good memory, you'll know you used some functionality that was introduced in a recent version. Even if you don't know what version specifically, you can look it up quickly in the documentation.
5. Some people embark with the intent to support a specific version, and always keep that in mind when developing. Even if it happens to work on other versions, they'd consider it unsupported and don't claim compatibility.

So, you could either limit yourself to 2.7 (it's been out for three years), or perform tests on older releases. If you just want to determine *whether* it's compatible, not which incompatibilities there are and how they can be fixed, you can:

1. Search the What's New pages for new features, most importantly new syntax, which you used.
2. Check the version constraints of third party libraries you used.
3. Search the documentation of standard library modules you use for newly added functionality.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you're going to maintain compatibility with previous versions, testing is the way to go. Even if your code happens to be compatible now, it can stop being so at any moment in the future if you don't pay attention.

2) If backwards compatibility is not an objective but just a "nice side-feature for those lucky enough", an easy way for OSS is to let users try it out, noting that "it was tested in `<version>` but may work in previous ones as well". If there's anyone in your user base interested in running your code in an earlier version (and maintain compatibility with it), they'll probably give you feedback. If there isn't, why bother?

Answer (score 1):

A lot easier with some test cases but manual testing can give you a reasonably idea.

Take the furthest back version that you would hope to support, (I would suggest 2.5.x but further back if you must - manually test with that version keeping notes of what you did and especially where it fails if any where - if it does fail then either address the issue or do a binary search to see which version the failure point(s) disappear at.  This could work even better if you start from a version that you are quite sure you will fail at, 2.0 maybe.